# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' error - when trying to append Array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to append my String Array with songs titles only, but when I do it inside my ForEach loop I have an error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'.

Why? And how can I correct it?

Here is my main view code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  VideoSearch
//
//  Created by Nikita Kolomoec on 13.01.2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var titleArray = [""]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(model.songs) { song in
                    titleArray.append(song.title)

                    NavigationLink {
                        VideoView(url: song.url, title: song.title)
                    } label: {
                        Text(song.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("All Videos")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: `titleArray.append(song.title)` code like this should not be inside of the `body` property of your `View`. Perform that code in a modifier like `onAppear` instead.

Comment: Agreed with Joakim. `body` *describes* the View. It cannot modify things. If this worked, it would be an infinite loop, because every time a `@State` property changes, the `body` needs to be reevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
@State private var titleArray = [""]
```

when you need an refer to an array of the titles you can just use

```
model.songs.map(\.title)
```